# Strat code engine using 'ibmcloud ce' ctl error: configuration error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I am new to use ibmcloud ctl.
My OS is Windows 11

I install the ibmcloud ctl from doc(for Windows users), and then I login, no problem.
And then I install plugin 'code-engine' using `ibmcloud plugin install code-engine`, and do a `ibmcloud plugin show code-engine`, the result is good, it installed well.

But when I want to use it, I try this command `ibmcloud ce`, there is an configuration error:

```
panic: configuration error: write C:\Users\Y9GD7E706\.bluemix\config.json: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/plugin.InitPluginContext.func1({0x2ab1320?, 0xc000c10ff0?})
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/plugin/plugin_shim.go:55 +0x59
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/bluemix/configuration/core_config.(*bxConfig).init.func1()
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/bluemix/configuration/core_config/bx_config.go:116 +0x48
sync.(*Once).doSlow(0xc00044bd80?, 0x2aec810?)
        /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.20.3.linux.amd64/src/sync/once.go:74 +0xc2
sync.(*Once).Do(...)
        /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.20.3.linux.amd64/src/sync/once.go:65
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/bluemix/configuration/core_config.(*bxConfig).init(0x2f?)
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/bluemix/configuration/core_config/bx_config.go:113 +0x45
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/bluemix/configuration/core_config.(*bxConfig).read(0xc000f4f020?, 0xc00114fc10)
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/bluemix/configuration/core_config/bx_config.go:125 +0x1e
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/bluemix/configuration/core_config.(*bxConfig).Locale(0x2af1d60?)
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/bluemix/configuration/core_config/bx_config.go:393 +0x4e
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/plugin.StartWithArgs({0x2ab61d8, 0xc00044b840}, {0xc00008c3d0?, 0x1, 0x1})
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/plugin/plugin_shim.go:36 +0x264
github.com/IBM-Cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk/plugin.Start(...)
        /home/travis/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/!i!b!m-!cloud/ibm-cloud-cli-sdk@v1.0.2/plugin/plugin_shim.go:15
main.main()
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.ibm.com/coligo/cli/main.go:18 +0x6e
```

But I close all the process except ibmcloud terminal, I don't know why.
My ibmcloud ctl version is: 2.16.0
and my ibmcloud ce plugin version is: 1.43.1

and more information: I have no problem to use other ibmcloud plugin like cr

Please help me to solve this problem.

I want to use ibmcloud ce ctl to deploy my app, but I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with this specific version of the CLI plugin. I suggest to use the previous version until a new release comes out with a fix.
You can force the older version with this installation command:

```
ibmcloud plugin install code-engine -v 1.43.0 -f
```

Comment: Thanks ! the version 1.43.0 can use in my system !

Comment: A new version is available. You can update with this command `ibmcloud plugin update code-engine`